# How do I clamp this old sink onto a new countertop?

Tags: kitchens, sink, countertops

Looking for innovative ideas on how I can clamp this older recycled stainless steel sink onto a new composite countertop that is 3/4" thick.

The sink has an inward lip around the perimeter, but doesn't have any clamps whatsoever. I'm thinking I can use that lip, but not sure how just yet.

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the cabinet set up from the front? Normally, the kitchen sink cabinet is quite large and open and the sink would clamp to the countertop, but your cabinets seem oddly aligned to me.

Comment: Gotta pic of the *top* of the flange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the counter overhung the cabinet opening a little as it is supposed to you could use sink clips [like these](https://www.build.com/product/summary/646191).  Given your unusual opening with no overhang you would have to make your own clips.  Since it's a drop-in sink I would attempt to just use silicone and see how that goes.

If the silicone isn't enough, you could try cutting little slits in the sides of the cabinet to accept the clips, using a rotary tool.

Comment: Those clips won't work unfortunately with the countertop as it is too thick. However that's an interesting idea to chisel the countertop edges to allow the clips to fit.

Comment: Ended up replacing the sink with a newer drop-in that has the U-channel brackets and the clips.

Comment: But what did you clip them to?   Usually they clip to the underside of the counter, but in your case the cabinet walls come up flush to the top of the counter.

Comment: Ah I see, no there was plenty of underside of the counter to clip to, the photos here are misleading. The new sink had a larger countertop cutout dimension, so it was a real pain to make a bigger cutout with the countertop already glued to the cabinets. Used the recip saw in contorted ways and got dust everywhere. Eventually it all worked out but the lesson: being thrifty sometimes means twice the effort.